# .NET nanoFramework deploy issue on nucleo STM32F746GZ

Tags: deployment, nanoframework

I flashed the community version "STMicroelectronics NUCLEO144-F746ZG" and try to upload a "hello world" piece of code from VS2019 without success. The messages in the output window is:

23:44:58.947 [*** ERROR: failed to get device execution state, aborting deployment ***]

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I started the project with the latest NuGet packages but had, what i thought, a mismatch between mscorlib and the firmware version.
My Nucleo device shows to have "Native Assemblies: mscorlib v100.5.0.6, checksum 0x7B586F51"
I selected nanoFramework.CoreLibrary version 1.10.3.7 because i thought they should match.
Maybe i didn't get the whole story of versions.

Anyhow i just returned to the latest Corelibrary 1.10.5 and have the following messages:

[Starting debug engine on nanoDevice]
[Connecting to debug engine...OK]
[nanoDevice is STM32, checking for flash dump on cache]
[Found flash dump on cache @ "C:\Users\schel\source\repos\NFApp1\NFApp1\bin\Debug\ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG @ COM4 - 1.6.977.977.dumpcache".]
[Couldn't find a valid native assembly required by mscorlib v1.10.5.4, checksum 0x132BDB6F]
[The connected target does not have support for mscorlib.]
[Starting debug engine on nanoDevice]
[Connecting to debug engine...OK]
[nanoDevice is STM32, checking for flash dump on cache]
[Couldn't find a flash dump for this nanoDevice. Setting up one now. This can take a couple of minutes...]
[Flash dump stored @ "C:\Users\schel\source\repos\NFApp1\NFApp1\bin\Release\ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG @ COM4 - 1.6.977.977.dumpcache".]
[Couldn't find a valid native assembly required by mscorlib v1.10.5.4, checksum 0x132BDB6F]
[The connected target does not have support for mscorlib.]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've updated all the NuGet to the latest preview versions, rebuild and deploy.

Comment: I updated my question, can you please have a look and advise? I also switch from the community nucleo to discovery board but it seems i am missing something because i get the same information as my updated message above.

Comment: You have a mismatch between fw and nugets. If you're using preview firmware, you should use preview NuGets. If stable, then all stable.
Check the FAQ entry [here](https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/faq/working-with-vs-extension.html#when-deploying-an-application-i-get-a-message-like-couldnt-find-a-valid-native-assembly-required-by-complaining-that-it-cant-find-a-native-assembly-what-can-i-do-to-fix-this).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with ESP32. I was using the latest preview version of nanoFramework.CoreLibrary (1.12.0-preview.9). Here is how I fixed the problem.

I Flashed the ESP32 to preview version. From Developer PowerShell tab on visual studio issue the following command:

```
nanoff --update --preview --platform ESP32 --serialport COM7
```

If you notice, I forced the firmware to the latest "preview" version. Also, I am using `--platform` instead of `--target` option. In your case, I think, your platform is STM32 and you you need to adjust the COM port to the port your STM32 is connected.

Another note: If you are using a latest stable version of nanoFramework.CoreLibrary (not the preview) do the following from Developer PowerShell:

```
nanoff --update --stable --platform ESP32 --serialport COM7
```